# ImageMapster JavaScript Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, imagemap, imagemapster

I would like to make this example of an image map,

http://jsfiddle.net/sb9j7/

but I want once you click on the active areas of the map instead of just appear simple text, I want that in that area appear two buttons that will call a database in that same area.

***Example***
Click on the carrots map>instead of text in the upper part appear two buttons>that button once is click calls a database

The problem is that this area only let me put simple text, don't let me make a button on the  `var xref = {carrots:`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, thank you In advanced for your guidance.

Comment: click on carrots  http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/sb9j7/5684/  and about calls a database you need to use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Could you give me an example the $.ajax() . Thank you, you were very helful Mohamed.

Comment: As I said you need to searching for $.ajax .. if you are using php just google for ajax and php you will find tons of results in stakeoverflow talking about that

Comment: Thank you Mohamed you are awesome!!! How can I close this question and give you the credit?

Comment: Thanks .. Good Luck :)